# What is the strength of the Shredder Chrome app?

Tags: engines, rating

Today, for the first time, I played against the Chrome app [Shredder Chess](http://chromefree.shredderchess.com/), and at the "**Hard**" playing strength of the engine, I was easily able to beat it.

I am just about 1850-1900 Elo.  My question here is, what (Elo) strength does this engine play at? Can someone evaluate?

I would suggest players to play against it to check its strength.

Comment: I played a few very, very fast games and I would estimate that it is no more than 1400 strength, maybe less, although tactically it might be as strong as 1600 strength.  These are just my own estimates, so take them with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a response from the maker of shredder. Hope it helps!

> We are using a different Shredder version on the Chrom App so this is
>   very hard to tell in Elo, even for us.

Best regards
Stefan Meyer-Kahlen

Comment: So the Shredder people don't know how strong their app is. Really?  Really?

Comment: This answer keeps the question unanswered. How can this be accepted as an answer? The Shredder people say it's hard, but why? And because it's hard, doesn't mean it is not possible to determine ELO strength.

Answer (score 0):

I can quite easily beat the iphone app when it is supposedly playing at 2600 Elo. I'm not that good! Very disappointing really.

Answer (score 0):

Ironically I've just played my first few games against it.  On its medium setting it twice overlooked a material winning pawn fork, so it may not even be looking two moves (4 ply ahead).  In my mind, that makes it less than average ELO strength.